# Reading class variable

Tags: c++, class, member

I created a class named "Triangle" and am now trying to read out a certain class-variable ("SideA") from the main-section. I especially declared SideA as "public" to prevent access problems. 
However, when trying to compile, the program throws the error "class Triangle has no member named SideA".

I'm pasting the most important parts for you:

```
class Triangle
{
public:
float SideA;
};

int main ()
{
Triangle Object(); //pair is normally filled with several vars for the constructor)

//I declared "Object" correctly, it can be constructed. "SideA" is filled by the 
//constructor. I'm just leaving it out 
//right now to keep this text short

//This line is marked when the IDE aborts the compiling process
cout << Object.SideA;
```

I hope you can help me, cause I really have no idea how to solve this problem. The books I'm learning from are suggesting to use special functions for these purposes ("void readOut {return X}"), but do I really have to write a function every time I want to read out a single number?

Thank you in advance,
JustATestAcc

Comment: Normally, these pairs are filled with floats for the constructor, I just left it out

Comment: Thank you all for your answers

Comment: @JustATestAcc If you have problems with code, isolate a minimal example which reproduces the problem *and then post the actual code* of that example. No simplifications "just for SO." Since you have a problem you can't solve, you cannot correctly judge what is relevant and what is not (otherwise, you'd know what the problem is). *Always* make sure that the code you post exactly reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer: MVP = Most Vexing Parse = Declaring a function with no arguments that is meant to be a variable declaration. In other words, the error you just made.

Comment: I'm sorry, didnt know. Shall I open a new question or just overwrite the old one?

Answer (score 3):

Try to update

```
Triangle Object();  // This declares a function which returns Triangle type
```

to

```
Triangle Object;    // this defines Object
```

Also read [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

If you C++11, you could initialize `Object` with [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

```
Triangle Object{};    // value-initialization (to zero)
Triangle Object{2.0}; // direct-list-initialization
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it `Triangle Object`;

try below..;)

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class Triangle
{
public:
float SideA;
};

int main ()
{
Triangle Object; //this defines object

//I declared "Object" correctly, it can be constructed. "SideA" is filled by the
//constructor. I'm just leaving it out
//right now to keep this text short

//This line is marked when the IDE aborts the compiling process
cout << Object.SideA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't create an instance of Triangle when you write this:

```
Triangle Object();
```

This locally (in the scope of main() ) declares a function `Object` with an empty argument list and a return type of `Triangle`. It does not instantiate an object of type `Triangle` and therefore doesn't call the instance's default constructor. However, the latter is what you obviously intended.

You can fix it by simply writing:

```
Triangle Object;
cout << Object.SideA;
```

Furthermore, I suggest you don't start variable names with an upper-case letter. In many coding conventions, and as you already did with `Triangle`, types start with an upper-case letter. The actual instance of `Triangle`, might later be confused with the name of a type and not recognized as the name of an instance of a type. From the context the name is used in it will become obvious what it really is, but having to scan the context of something just to find out what it actually represents is tedious and unnecessary:

```
Triangle object;
cout << object.SideA;
```

Comment: Thank you. However, its normally like "Triangle Object(kathA, kathB, hyp);", because I need these vars for the constructor. The triangle also can be created, I just cannot read SideA out.

Comment: I don't quite get what you're trying to say. If you do that you will call a constructor Triangle::Triangle(T kathA, T kathB, T hyp) (I assume your triangle edges are all represented by the same type). Whether or not SideA is still apublic member is orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

```
Triangle Object();  // Declare a function Object return a Triangle
```

This can be two things :

1. a variable definition for variable Object of class Triangle
2. a function declaration for a function Object which returns an object of type Triangle

The C++ standard requires that this lign has to be interpreted as the second point.

It is called the [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

You can change it by :

```
Triangle Object;
```

Or in C++11 :

```
Tirangle Object{}; // Useful when parameters are needed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do , Triangle *Object = new Triangle();
or,          Triangle Object;